# Django | Una relación a sí mismo bien, pero dos relaciones a sí mismo en el mismo modelo devuelve error

Tags: django, django-models

Si el modelo tiene una relación a si misma:

```
origin_watertank = models.ForeignKey ('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

...no hay ningún problema, pero si hay dos relaciónes a sí misma en el mismo modelo:

```
origin_watertank = models.ForeignKey ('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
comunication_point =  models.ForeignKey ('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

develve error.

**Error:**

```
ERRORS:
station.Station.comunication_point: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Station.comunication_point' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Station.origin_watertank'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Station.comunication_point' or 'Station.origin_watertank'.
station.Station.origin_watertank: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'Station.origin_watertank' clashes with reverse accessor for 'Station.comunication_point'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'Station.origin_watertank' or 'Station.comunication_point'.
```

Si el problema es que los dos tienen como nombre el mismo "self", pruebo cambiar uno de ellos por "self2" pero devuelve error:

**Error:**

```
ValueError: Cannot create form field for 'origin_watertank' yet, because its related model 'self2' has not been loaded yet
```

**Archivo** models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from .managers import StationManager

# Create your models here.

class Station(models.Model):
    timestamp_station = models.DateTimeField ('Fecha edición',null=True, blank=True)
    code_station = models.CharField('Código',max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)
    name_station = models.CharField('Nombre',max_length=50,null=True, blank=True)

    origin_watertank = models.ForeignKey ('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    comunication_point =  models.ForeignKey ('self', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    
    objects = StationManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Estación'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Estaciones'

    def __str__(self):
        #return  [self.name,self.area,self.codigo]
        return str(self.id) + '-' + str(self.name_station)
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Prueba esto a ver para el error:**

```
 origin_watertank = models.ForeignKey ('self',related_name="origin", null=True, 
 on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
 comunication_point =  models.ForeignKey ('Station',related_name="comunication", null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
```

Comment: Dice: SyntaxError: invalid syntax (y señala el igual de related_name). ¿Qué puede ser? Gracias.

Comment: Pon en related_name="origin", related_name="comunication"  Esto funciona al hacer makemigrations sin errores.El resto todo igual. Ah si te funciona puntuame que necesito subir.saludos

Comment: con related_name="origin" funciona perfecto. Lo que no comprendo por qué no le puuedo llamar de la misma manera que el índice "origin_watertank". No me importa, pero por comprenderlo. Gracias.

Comment: Ni idea soy principiante pero me gusta buscar errores.gracias

Comment: Ok gracias de todos modos. Un saludo samuandis!